# EXCEL - Circular Reference Error when Entering Data

Tags: excel

I've got another one that is really kicking my butt.

I know why the error is occurring. I just don't know how to fix it. There are a lot of IF statements so I'm thinking maybe they are arranged in a way that is causing the error. I'm sure there is a much cleaner way to write them.

Whenever I try to input data into D7 or E7 I get the circular reference error.

These are my current formulas for all relevant cells:

**F7:** =IF(C7<0,"FAIL",IF(OR(ISBLANK(B7),ISBLANK(C7))," ",IF(ABS(F8)<=30,"PASS","FAIL")))

**G7:** =IF(D7<0,"FAIL",IF(OR(ISBLANK(B7),ISBLANK(D7))," ",IF(ABS(G8)<=30,"PASS","FAIL")))

**H7:** =IF(E7<0,"FAIL",IF(OR(ISBLANK(B7),ISBLANK(E7))," ",IF(ABS(H8)<=30,"PASS","FAIL")))

**F8:** =IF(B7<0,"",IF(C7<0,"",IF(D7<0,"",IF(E7<0,"",IF(G7="FAIL","",IF(H7="FAIL","",IF(ISBLANK(B7),IF(ISBLANK(C7),"","input Lw_Lw"),IF(ISBLANK(C7),"input Lw_Up",SUM(C7-B7)))))))))

**G8:** =IF(B7<0,"",IF(C7<0,"",IF(D7<0,"",IF(E7<0,"",IF(F7="FAIL","",IF(H7="FAIL","",IF(ISBLANK(B7),IF(ISBLANK(D7),"","input Lw_Lw"),IF(ISBLANK(D7),"input Up_Lw",SUM(D7-B7)))))))))

**H8:** =IF(B7<0,"",IF(C7<0,"",IF(D7<0,"",IF(E7<0,"",IF(G7="FAIL","",IF(F7="FAIL","",IF(ISBLANK(B7),IF(ISBLANK(E7),"","input Lw_Lw"),IF(ISBLANK(E7),"input Up_Up",SUM(E7-B7)))))))))

[Snip of Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRAqa.png)

[image]
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I cant reproduce the error you find, perhaps because of my Excel version (365) but I do get a #VALUE error from `ABS(F8)<=30`. This could be because F8 isn't numeric and it could be another way expressing the illegal interdependence between F7 and F8. Apparently F8 can only be numeric if the formula there returns `SUM(C7-B7)`. In that case you could resolve the issue with `=IF(C7<0,"FAIL",IF(OR(ISBLANK(B7),ISBLANK(C7))," ",IF(ABS(SUM(C7-B7))<=30,"PASS","FAIL")))`

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the following two formulas for you. Please try them.

```
[F7] =IF(IFERROR(ABS(F8)<=30,FALSE),"PASS","FAIL")
[F8] ==IF(ISBLANK(C7),"input "&F$3,IF(OR(COUNT($B7:$E7)<4,COUNTIF($B7:$E7,"<0")>0),"",SUM(C7-$B7)))
```

Copy them from F7:F8 to G7:H8.

The basic principle I applied in order to avoid a circular reference is to do all testing in row 8 with the outcome that F8 will either hold a blank or a number. Therefore "Pass" or "Fail" in row 7 can be decided based on the number: If the number is within range it's a PASS, else it's failed. Note that `Abs("")` will cause an error. Therefore `IFERROR(ABS(F8)<=30,FALSE)` will return *False* in case F8 = "". Effectively, this is the reverse of what I wrote in my comment above.

I looked for shorter expressions for other tests as well. `Count()` will only count cells with numbers in them. Therefore I use this function instead of a series of ISBLANK() queries. Similarly for `COUNTIF($B7:$E7,"<0")`.

I used mixed absolute and relative addressing to enable copying formulas to other columns and referred to the column captions in place of repeating the same texts in the formulas.

I didn't fully test my solution. However, with my above explanation as a guide you should be able to take possession and eliminate any errors I might have left behind.

Comment: Hi Variatus, Thank you so much for your help. Your second answer worked up until I added IF(G7="FAIL","",IF(H7="FAIL","", then I received the circular reference error again. I used the formula from your first post and was able to tweak the formula a bit for it to work every which way I needed :)

Comment: Sorry about the error in my initial solution. Of course, `Abs("")` causes an error. I was hoping you hadn't seen it yet. In the "second post" values below zero are counted even simpler. For the benefit of onlookers, please do post the solution you worked out by yourself. Thank you.